# "Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function" vanishes after computer restarted

Tags: javascript, reactjs, webpack, webpack-dev-server

I'm building a React component library using `rollup` for the build and `webpack-dev-server` to run a demo. While hacking away last night, using the demo to see my changes, I was running into an `Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function` that would simply not go away as long as a certain line was included in my code.

The line of code was `defaultCheckboxRender(CheckboxComponent, label);` but please just assume that sufficient debugging was done to determine that none of those identifiers were undefined and that all were within the proper scope. After slamming my head on this for several hours, I shut down my **Windows 10** computer to install some updates and went to bed. This morning, I boot up my project, run the demo to continue this nightmare and, lo and behold, the error is gone. I did not change the code since I last encountered the error but for some reason, it's not happening anymore.

Now... I set up the webpack config myself and it was the first time I have done such a thing. My best guess is that this problem is related to how the files are served and compiled and such. Here is the `webpack.config.js` file https://gist.github.com/dumptruckman/db7001568077497fe1aaa0b4db9d8424. One thing to note is that when I run my demo, I do not see a dist folder appear in my project directory which struck me as kind of odd but I'm not sure why it's like that.

Has anyone experienced anything like this before and how do I prevent it from happening in the future?

Answer (score 1):

This was resolved by adding HotModuleReplacementPlugin to my webpack config. The updated config can be seen here: https://gist.github.com/dumptruckman/7de7ff7e9526bff4408f0cea6fb4bbe5